# Cannot download tagged artifacts in teamcity

Tags: download, teamcity, artifacts

The documentation of teamcity explains how to download builded artifacts by using the tag version.

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/BUILD_TAG.tcbuildtag/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

My build is tagged with version 1.5 but when I launch the following url, I get a 404.

```
http://<tcurl>/repository/download/<buildtype>/1.5.tcbuildtag/<artifact>-1.5.tgz
```

The build is also tagged in Teamcity and pinned.

Using the build_id:id syntax works but this is not something that can be used when deploying with ansible because the BUILD_ID is variable.

```
/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/BUILD_ID:id/ARTIFACT_PATH
```

Does anyone know how you can download teamcity artifacts with a tag version?

Regards,

Jelle

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar issue in TC forum:
https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206837375-Problems-downloading-artifacts-when-using-build-tag

It seems you have to specify a branch if you have no builds with a particular tag in your default branch (usually master).
Adding `?branch=<branch>` to get parameters solved the issue for me. Result URLs are:

```
https://<tcurl>/repository/download/<buildtype>/<tag>.tcbuildtag/<artifact>?branch=<branch>
https://<tcurl>/repository/downloadAll/<buildtype>/<tag>.tcbuildtag?branch=<branch>
```